# Sails.js template helper (filter) with promise

Tags: sails.js, ejs

I'm just getting into Sails.js and was wondering if there was a way with the EJS templating system to have a helper function run which includes a promise or database query. This works:

in config/http.js:

```
module.exports.http = {
  // ...
  locals: {
    filters: {
      testHelper: function(input) { return input; }
    }
  }
}
```

This does not:

```
module.exports.http = {
  // ...
  locals: {
    filters: {
      testHelper: function(input) {
            MyModal.create({test:'test'}).exec(function(err,mm){
                  return input+'-'+mm.test;
              });
          }
    }
  }
}
```

The first always returns "check", the second always returns "undefined" when used in a template `"{{ 'check' | testHelper }}"`

Answer (score 1):

You could using a library like [wait.for](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait.for) to wrap and return the promise. I would suggest creating your "helper" as a service and accessing it off the global scope instead of injecting it in your view.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I've had a look at the "wait.for" library and it looks great, any chance you could post any example of how I do this using the above filter as an example?